# Does MariaDB support server-side query rewriting?

Tags: mariadb, query, plugins

MySQL has something called "[The Rewriter Query Rewrite Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rewriter-query-rewrite-plugin.html)". I've tried to find info about anything similar in MariaDB but so far found nothing. Is there any way in MariaDB to examine and modify SQL statements received by the server before the server executes them? Or is it possible (and safe) to use MySQL plugins in MariaDB 10+?

EDIT: I just found out that [work on "Query Rewrite Plugin API" on MariaDB side is "stalled"](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-5561). BUT in the comments people mention that there are some workarounds by using existing audit plugins. I am looking for any info about that.

EDIT 2: I know that third-party software (like MaxScale or ProxySQL) can be used as a proxy with capabilities to rewrite queries but this is not what I am asking about. I ask about query rewrite mechanisms that utilise only MariaDB server engine/package.

Comment: If you're willing to help implement the Query Rewrite Plugin API that would be most welcome. Is there a specific problem you are solving that might be achieved another way?

Comment: What things do you want to change in query?  You can use ProxySQL for query rewriting.

Comment: @JYOTIRAJAI I want to force specific indexes to be used

Comment: Yes you can do it with ProxySQL.

Comment: Is any mysql proxy available on Alpine linux (because ProxySQL will never run on it)?

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski - Do you have a specific example of an index failing to be used?  Start a new Question so we can discuss that.